# How to aggregate all the variables (columns except the one on which it is done) of data frame separately with 1 column

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I have a data frame of 10 columns. I wanted to perform aggregation of all 9 columns one by one with 10th column and store result in 9 different data frames.

Suppose my data frame is df ; So,I want

```
aggregate(df[10] ~ df[1], data = df, sum)  
aggregate(df[10] ~ df[2], data = df, sum)
```

.. and so on. But when I try to do this I get the following error

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = data_bi[1] ~ data_bi[2], data =
>   data_bi) :    invalid type (list) for variable 'data_bi[1]'

Is there any way possible to do this.(I know that by giving the column name instead of df[1]... this can be done, but I don`t want to do that )

Comment: You may need `aggregate(col10~col1, df, sum)`  whatever the column name is.  This can be done in a `list` using `lapply` by looping through the column names.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example